# Ventless Gas Fireplace Odor After Replacing Pilot Assembly

Tags: fireplace

I have a Superior VF5000 Ventless fireplace that started acting up.  Initially it wouldn't light so I gently sanded down the assembly and cleaned it out which worked initially.  A few weeks later it would turn on, stay on for a few minutes then turn off and repeat off and on.  So I researched and decided to replace the entire assembly.
Now it works but it is emitting a stronger odor then it ever had before when lit.  When only the pilot is on there is a very, very slight normal odor when your right up next to the unit.  And no odor whatsoever when the gas is turned off.  The connections are tight so I don't think there is a leak. I re-positioned the logs so that they aren't over the lines.  Should I expect an odor from the new assembly until it is "broken in"?  Or does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Is the new unit set up to burn the same fuel as the one you replaced? Different fuels require different orfices and supply pressures. If every thing is okay with the installation, I would fire the unit for a few hours to "break it in", then check for odors. You may also want an installer to check the firing rate to make sure it is not being overfired.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes it is the same fuel, the only thing changed is the replaced assembly.  And I used the manufacturers recommended replacement part.  So there is potentially a "break in period"?